# Open Graph issue for Facebook 'like' button on Wordpress site - too many redirects?

Tags: wordpress, facebook-opengraph

G'day

I'm having some trouble getting the facebook 'like' button to work correctly. The site in question is http://etincellebyemilie.com.au/casual-afternoon-tea/

The button is added to the page using the following code...

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()); ?>&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=60&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:80px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

When the button is clicked, the like is registered and appears on the users facebook page. But, the link back to the site produces a 310 error and states **'There are too many redirects'**, as you can see by visiting the generated URL - http://etincellebyemilie.com.au/casual-afternoon-tea/?fb_action_ids=10151158453571916&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=timeline_og&action_object_map=%7B%2210151158453571916%22%3A581712555188197%7D&action_type_map=%7B%2210151158453571916%22%3A%22og.likes%22%7D&action_ref_map=%5B%5D

I have tested this URL using the Facebook object debugger and the results tell me that **The 'og:url' property is required, but not present**.

This doesn't make a lot of sense because I can see that the meta tags *are* in the document head - all the og tags have been generated by the Yoast SEO plugin.

```
<meta property='og:locale' content='en_US'/>
<meta property='og:title' content='Casual Afternoon Tea - Etincelle By Emille'/>
<meta property='og:url' content='http://etincellebyemilie.com.au/casual-afternoon-tea/'/>
<meta property='og:site_name' content='Etincelle By Emille'/>
<meta property='og:type' content='article'/>
<meta property='og:image' content='http://etincellebyemilie.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Maganda.jpg'/>
```

If anyone has some idea on where to go with this I would love to hear it.

Cheers

Comment: Your url http://etincellebyemilie.com.au/casual-afternoon-tea/?fb_action_ids=10151158453571916&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=timeline_og&action_object_map=%7B%2210151158453571916%22%3A581712555188197%7D&action_type_map=%7B%2210151158453571916%22%3A%22og.likes%22%7D&action_ref_map=%5B%5D returns `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` to itself. Do you have any redirection plugin?

Comment: There aren't any redirection plugins installed. I know the hosing company use Zeus instead of Apache, which is what is throwing me (I'm an apache user and am used to htaccess files).  I have contacted the hosting company to see what they come up with. 

Thanks for bringing that to my attention! It is strange that the url without the parameters has no redirects, but with all the added parameters, it does.